# Updating multiple records - poor performance

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql, join

I'm wondering why it takes forever to execute statement below using postgres:

```
UPDATE left_table AS l
SET some_col=r.some_col
FROM right_table AS r
WHERE l.uid=r.uid
```

Both tables have index on column `uid` (datatype varchar(50))

Both tables have nearly `500k` rows.

There's no duplicate `uid`-s, so

> target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s)

should not be the case.

while simple join like this

```
SELECT * FROM  
left_table AS l
INNER JOIN
right_table as r
ON l.uid=r.uid
```

returns immediately (takes less than 1 sec), first one takes more than 30 minutes

**EDIT:**

output of explain

```
"Update on left_table l  (cost=37989.79..575033.10 rows=484302 width=4270)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=37989.79..575033.10 rows=484302 width=4270)"
"        Hash Cond: ((l.uid)::text = (r.uid)::text)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on left_table l  (cost=0.00..17307.02 rows=484302 width=4261)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=27679.02..27679.02 rows=484302 width=47)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on right_table r  (cost=0.00..27679.02 rows=484302 width=47)"
```

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN and/of EXPLAIN ANALYZE? And did you check for (row) locks?

Comment: Can you please give a hint how should I check for row locks?

Comment: Check pg_stat_activity and the column "waiting". And what does EXPLAIN ANALYZE tell you? It does execute the update, you could execute it within a transactions and rollback afterwards.

Comment: I've executed "select pid from pg_stat_activity where waiting" parallel to UPDATE statement and it returned nothing. Is it possible to print results of EXPLAIN ANALYZE until it's finished?. I can't wait for it all time :)

Comment: Thanks @Frank for your advice, finally found out the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/using-explain.html) on a reduced dataset and turned out that I was doing something expensive in trigger. So anyone with similar problem, remember: **EXPLAIN ANALYZE** is your friend